# What is the word for the resentful feeling you experience when being accused of something you intentionally avoided doing?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

For example, I always put conscious effort into only asking questions that I can't find the answer to for myself and not wasting people's time.  In light of this, say I ask person a question, and the person responds by implying that I am wasting their time and could have found the answer to the question on my own.  This results in a galling, resentful feeling.  What is the name for that feeling?

"Defensive" seems too broad.

Comment: What’s wrong with *resentment*?

Comment: It could well be too specific, with no definitive answer. Answers so far are ballpark. But there _are_ a claimed 1 000 000+ words in the lexicon, so time may prove my suspicion wrong.

Comment: Word for the *disparity* felt from *a disconnect* formed while being *misunderstood*? 'resentful' sounds like you got *trolled* by someone who doesn't know how to *stack exchange* a question into something informative, as to *why* (*you don't understand*), instead of responding LMGTFY. - *alone*; the reason why I come here. Until someone says lmgtfy and I remember that, I still am, and will be, no matter what the answers are. *Apathy, despondence*? Depends on how close to 'the bottom' you are. Sounds like you're still too *irritated* to be anywhere close.

Comment: I'm not going to post this as an answer, because it's more about psychology rather than the English language, but there are different feelings that people might have in that situation; it could also depend on your relative status to the one who accuses you. Most of the answers have focused on the "resentment" part of your question. I'd say you might feel **alienation**. You first believed your efforts would earn you the benefit of the doubt within the community, then you found out the community is not like that, and you were excluded from the community activity of asking and receiving answers.

Comment: This is only about opinions about this.

Answer (score 23):

My gut reaction to your prompt is “indignation” but do you consider that also too general?

Comment: Better yet, righteous indignation.

Comment: "Indignation" might be the best word in the lexicon to answer my question.  It's not exactly there, maybe 95%.  Perhaps an English word to capture the remaining 5% doesn't exist?

Comment: @JesseDowning To combine this with another answer: "Indignation at the misjudgement" is a phrase that I think gets a bit closer

Comment: How about a source for this unsupported but true gut feeling?  Am I indignantly resigned to [edit] in a dictionary definition and link per the [help]?

Answer (score 5):

You could say you feel "misjudged." This points out that the person is being judgmental, that the judgment is in error, and to a lesser extent implies that it is personally hurtful.

Answer (score 2):

> I ask person a question, and the person responds by implying that I am wasting their time and could have found the answer to the question on my own. This results in a galling, resentful feeling. What is the name for that feeling?

This appears to be **resentfulness**: Your feeling are resentful that the person did not choose to help you.

OED:

> **Sense of grievance; inclination to feel resentful; rancour; bitterness.** Also: an instance of this.
>
> 1735 The Avarice and Ambition of some, the Peevishness and
> Resentfulness of others. *G. Fothergill, Importance Relig. Civil
> Societies 7* … 2005 He is mild-mannered, too, and does not appear to
> share the ideological pugnaciousness and cultural resentfulness of his
> putative future colleagues. *New Yorker (Nexis) 14 November 37*

Depending on the nuance, **rancour** and **bitterness** in the definition might be used.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking how to respond to an irony. It is a 'contradiction', and you feel the sting of this contradiction. You have acquired an estimation of this person based upon something they cannot obviously see. You are 'outraged'. You find the alleged facts 'outrageous'. Perhaps that is the word, but you still have to explain why.
My natural reaction would be to call out the irony for what it was. I would begin the response with 'Considering that..'. In order to be most effective, be succinct, state the 2 facts, and avoid all emotion. To show emotion would mean you are affected by all of it, which would bring them satisfaction. In order to successfully employ a non-emotive answer, do not address the person, but the subject. Example: Instead of 'you accused me of' say 'the accusation seems to be..'.

Comment: "to harass, criticize, or antagonize (someone) especially by provocatively disparaging or mocking public statements, postings, or acts"

Comment: The question is asking for a _word_ to describe a feeling. It's not asking how to respond to an irony.

Comment: BTW 'Galling' as you had described it, is pretty much the word, but once again, we must leave out the personal. Saying 'You have the gall to..."  does not pull the punch.

Comment: Killing time, What I am saying in essence is the user of that word - whatever it is - must expand on it if they are actually employ what they want to say effectively. There was a practical reason behind wanting to find the word, and and I have offered this.

Answer (score 0):

"Indignation" can imply, sometimes, a phoniness or sense of entitlement.  Adding the qualifier "righteous" indignation can make the distinction that it is justified.   And of course, [making you] "resentful" is also expected and justified, although it is something which persists after the initial reaction of indignation.

Other words might be "jarring", "shocking", or "insulting."  The reaction of the person being asked the question could even be construed as "gaslighting" because it's designed to make you feel like there is something wrong with you instead of them. This word is increasing in popularity and I expect it to acquire subtle new meanings as time goes on.

Also "uncooperative", "arrogant" and "belligerent" come to mind and are self-explanatory, precise and parsimonious ways to describe that behavior to others, as well as describing your own shock. These words also load the retelling of the event in negative terms, which is a justified way of getting back at the original offender.

Or any combination of the above may be used.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest word would be

> **pique:** (or "fit of pique") a transient feeling of intense resentment or wounded vanity

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pique

It's not strictly limited to the situation you mention, but I think it captures the feeling very well

Comment: Pique does have a somewhat negative connotation, implying that the feeling of resentment may not be justified or may be exaggerated due to personal vanity.

Answer (score 0):

Are you feeling annoyed and disappointed at the same time? Perhaps you’re **vexed** . . .

> **vexed** *adj.* and *n.*
> **1.** Distressed, grieved, worried, annoyed, irritated; affected with vexation.
>  <sub>In predicative use often with clause as complement,
> expressing the source of distress, worry, irritation, etc.;
> predicative uses are sometimes difficult to distinguish from passive
> uses of **vex** *v.*</sub>
>
> **vexation** *noun*
> **3.a.** The state or fact of being mentally troubled or distressed; (in later use) *esp.* annoyance, irritation, dissatisfaction, or
> disappointment.
>
> <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

As a species we have really quite a small range of emotional responses, with each to varying intensities, but when asked to describe “what are we feeling” we tend take these emotional states and dress them up with a combination of post-facto justifications and imagined responses.

Those additional elements tend to be quite personal, and very specific to the circumstances, which makes the question as asked rather hard to give a simple answer to.

But even before those, there are a multiple possible responses.

We respond strongly to words because reputational harm can cause ostracism, and that can lead to real-word harm, up to and including starvation. Strong-enough negative emotions are often equated with *pain*.

An unjustified accusation may give rise to some degree of the irritation response, ranging somewhere between *annoyance* and *outrage*.

Anger justified by “unfairness” might be perceived as *resentment*.

If the party making the accusation is a trusted person, we would also feel *betrayal*.

A simple false accusation might be repudiated and dismissed as a mistaken, but when we've taken advance precautions it feels like we've already done the repudiation, and yet we are still being accused; that can feel like a deliberately harmful act, and a overwhelming desire to punish the false accuser may be lead to *rage*.

Or conversely, we may instead believe we've been seriously misunderstood, and wonder how we've given such a bad impression, leading to *melancholy* or more serious *depression*.

Assuming you want to focus more on *resentment*, there are still lots of options.

- Are you resentful of the falsehood of the accusation?
- Are you resentful that they failed to notice your precautions?
- Are you resentful because they're broadcasting the accusation rather than making it to you privately?
- Are there other contributing factors?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest "frustration" - because of being misuderstood.

It is very frustrating if the person responding to a question does not understand what you mean or doesn't listen carefully and responds in a way that makes it clear that they have not understood your question.

Answer (score -2):

This is taking a bit of a leap, but I think of "*unrequited*". Its usually used with "love" (unrequited love) but in general it can be used to describe any non-reciprocal situation

> "Unrequited" is a word that is often used to describe situations where
> there is an imbalance or lack of reciprocity. It's a word that can be
> used to express disappointment, sadness, or frustration when our
> **efforts** <strike>or feelings</strike> are not returned or acknowledged.

https://brainly.com/question/30552910

So in your context, the **effort** you have made to avoid doing something [researching the question] is unrequited.

Answer (score -3):

You are feeling the effects of "cognitive dissonance". And your emotions are a reaction to that.

Comment: Which two incompatible thoughts do you think the OP is describing themselves as having?